# Веб-приложение в IDEA: Tomcat сервлеты + сервер, связь RMI

Tags: java, web-apps, rmi, tomcat, intellij-idea

Хочу попробовать штуку, описанную в заголовке: веб-приложение, общающееся с неким сервером по RMI. Приложение и сервер работают на одной машине.
Я работаю в Intellij IDEA. Я правильно понимаю, что мне в этом случае нужно создать два отдельных проекта и в одном писать сервлеты и JSP, а в другом - сервер? Или есть какая-то функциональность для работы в одном проекте?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно просто создать два модуля в одном проекте.

Comment: Спасибо, то, что нужно!